# Rewrite path for nginx Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I need to point Ingress to images so that my Pods gets the URL, in full. I have the below config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: solar-demo
  annotations:
    nginx.org/server-snippet: "proxy_ssl_verify off;"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: shmukler.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /city/*
        backend:
          serviceName: solar-demo
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /solar/*
        backend:
          serviceName: solar-demo
          servicePort: 3001
```

If I keep the line: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`, my services inside the Pods get the rewritten paths, so `/city/dublin` becomes `/dublin`.

If I comment out the line `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`, I just get `503` errors on the client side, and nothing in the logs. With rewrite, my services give me `404` because there is no route `/dublin`.

What am I doing wrong? How could I just pass the path on and have the Pods respond?

```
$ kubectl describe svc solar-demo
Name:              solar-demo
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration= 
{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"solar-demo","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"city","port":3000...
Selector:          app=testapp
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.107.221.76
Port:              city  3000/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.3:3000,172.17.0.8:3000
Port:              solar  3001/TCP
TargetPort:        3001/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.3:3001,172.17.0.8:3001
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here should be a working config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: solar-demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: shmukler.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /city
        backend:
          serviceName: solar-demo
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /solar
        backend:
          serviceName: solar-demo
          servicePort: 3001
```

What changed:

- Removed `*` from paths
- Specified ingress in the annotation
- Removed re-write annotation

The `path` on an ingress (when using an `nginx` ingress) is like specifying the nginx `location` block. `nginx` does not use the `*` character in location blocks.

Comment: Thank you. It is not working for me on `minikube`. Still, I sure do appreciate the attempt. Good tip as far as referencing `ingress.class`. Yet, for me, it is clearly not working. If you are running minikube, what versions?

Comment: Also tried `nginx-internal` as a class. No errors, and the same 503 errors. On Azure Ingress is a Pod, so there are logs. The `addon` they have for `minikube` is awesome, but I was only able to get it working with `rewrite-target`, which is not ideal. Does not mean anything is wrong with an `addon`. Just makes it harder for uninitiated. :)

Comment: It was late at night when I wrote this. The trailing slash should not be there as well. My fault. I just removed the slash. Can you try with the above now?

Comment: just `/${path}` was the first thing that I tried. it works on Azure, but `minikube` wants `/${path}/*` for some reason.